# Creating reccuring events in Google Calendar using Google Calendar api v3 with javascript (jquery ajax POST)

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I am trying to create a series of calendar appointments using a JQuery Ajax Post using the Google Calendar api (v3) and a token from the identity link.

Just te be clear:
The request works, and the authentication works.
The only thing that isn't working is the recurrence...

data.recurrence = ["RDATE:20140308T000000"]

the rest of the fields are working.

Can someone please tell my why the recurring events are not added?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: link to my request: http://jsfiddle.net/YDcbb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by not using the JSON stringify function, and creating the request body as a String object. JSON changed " into /"